# How to design/redesign a JavaScript function to end and reset the rock paper scissors game after 9 rounds? The current function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, function, reset

The following code is the totality of a version of paper rock scissors. The function: limitGameToBestOutOfNine ()  is only working some of the time. There are instances where the user or computer score increments above 9 wins. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
/*variable statements follow*/
const computerChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById('computer-choice');
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('control');
const userChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById('player-choice');
const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('result');
const possibleChoices = document.getElementsByClassName('control');
const resultOutput = document.getElementById('result-output');
const playerImage = document.getElementById('player-image');
const computerImage = document.getElementById('computer-image');
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
let userChoice;
let computerChoice;
let result  ;
let playerChoice ;
let score = 0;
let mistakes = 0;
let scoreContainer;
let userSpan;
let computerSpan;
let playerScore = document.getElementById("userScore");
let compScore = document.getElementById("compScore");
let resetButton = document.getElementById("resetScore");
let compChoice;
let completedRounds = 0;

/**
 * This Array from statement sets event listener to the button class control array
 * which listens for the user and computer choices which are fed to the getresult function
 */
Array.from(possibleChoices).forEach(possibleChoice => possibleChoice.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    userChoice = e.target.id;
    resultDisplay.innerHTML = userChoice;
    compChoice = generateComputerChoice();
    gameImages(userChoice, computerChoice);

    getResult();
}));

/**
 * This adds an event listener for the reset button
 */
document.getElementById("resetScore").addEventListener("click", resetScore);


/**
 * This function generates a random number for the computer and displays
 * the output to the innerHTML
 */
function generateComputerChoice() {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    
    if (randomNumber === 1) {
        computerChoice = 'rock';
    }
    if (randomNumber === 2) {
        computerChoice = 'paper';
    }
    if (randomNumber === 3) {
        computerChoice = 'scissors';
    }
    computerChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = computerChoice;
}

/**
 * Provides the logic to determin what to do in the event that either 
 * the user or computer wins, as well as what to do in the even of a draw.
 */
function getResult () {
    if (computerChoice === userChoice) {
        result = "It's a draw!";
    }
    if (computerChoice === 'rock'  && userChoice === 'paper') {
        result = "You Win!";
        incrementUserScore();
        console.log("paperWin");
    }
    if (computerChoice === 'rock'  && userChoice === 'scissors') {
        result = "You lost!";
        incrementComputerScore();
    }
    if (computerChoice === 'paper'  && userChoice === 'scissors') {
        result = "You Win!";
        incrementUserScore();
    }
    if (computerChoice === 'paper'  && userChoice === 'rock') {
        result = "You lost!";
        incrementComputerScore();
    }
    if (computerChoice === 'scissors'  && userChoice === 'rock') {
        result = "You win!";
        incrementUserScore();
    }
    if (computerChoice === 'scissors'  && userChoice === 'paper') {
        result = "You lost!";
        incrementComputerScore();
    }
    resultOutput.innerHTML = result;
    toggleBackgroundColor()
}
    
/**
 * This function allows for the dynamic change of images based on user or 
 * computer choices.
 */
function gameImages(playerChoice, computerChoice) {
    console.log(playerChoice, computerChoice);

    playerImage.src = `assets/images/${playerChoice}.jpg`;
    playerImage.alt = choices [userChoice];

    computerImage.src = `assets/images/${computerChoice}.jpg`;
    computerImage.alt = choices[computerChoice];
}

/**
 * Gets the user score from the DOM and increments it by 1
 */
function incrementUserScore() {
    console.log("incrementing");
    // playerScore = playerScore++
    score++;
    playerScore.innerHTML = score;
    console.log(playerScore);
    completeRound()
}


/**
 * Gets the computer score from the DOM and increments it by 1
 */
function incrementComputerScore() {
    mistakes++;
    compScore.innerHTML = mistakes;
    console.log(compScore);
    completeRound()

}

/**
 * This function provides the logic used to reset the user and
 * computer score back to zero, upon the user request.
 */
function resetScore() {
    score = 0;
    mistakes = 0;
    playerScore.innerHTML = score;
    compScore.innerHTML = mistakes;  

}

/**
 * This function is to limit the amount of playable paper, rock, and scissors game to best out of 9
 */
function limitGameToBestOutOfNine () { 

    // Check who has the higher score
    if (score > mistakes) {
      console.log('Player has won the game!');
      alert('Player has won the game!');
    } else if (mistakes > score) {
      console.log('Computer has won the game!');
      alert('Computer has won the game!');
    } else {
      console.log('It\'s a tie!');
      alert('It\'s a tie!');
    }
  
    // Reset the scores 
    score = 0;
    mistakes = 0;
  }
  

function completeRound() {
        // increment a completed round
        completedRounds++;
        console.log("Completed Rounds: " + completedRounds)
        if (completedRounds == 10) {
            limitGameToBestOutOfNine()
        }
}

/***
 * This function toggles the background color of the .player .computer class
 * based on the winner of the current game. The winner color is green and the loser color is red
 */
function toggleBackgroundColor() {
    const player = document.getElementById('player');
    const computer = document.getElementById('computer');
    const winner = resultOutput.innerHTML.toLowerCase();

    console.log(winner)

    if (winner.includes('you win')) {
        console.log('win')
        player.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00"; 
        computer.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000"; 
    } 
    else if (winner.includes('you lost')) {
        console.log('lose')
        player.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000"; 
        computer.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } 
    else {
        console.log('draw')
        player.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00"; 
        computer.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    } 
}
```

I have reviewed the code and do not know what the issue is. The problem started happening after I added the toggleBackgroundColor() function.

Comment: You seem to be missing a lot of `;` after function calls. JavaScript isn't supposed to care, but sometimes it doesn't work out. Consistency is best practice there.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. You're absolutely right. Will clean that up and see if that helps.

Comment: I would advise that you change this `if (completedRounds == 10) { ... }` to this `if (completedRounds > 9) { ... }`. The reason - if there's an error in incrementation of your counter, and something makes the counter go above 10 rounds, your original condition will never pass, which will make you go beyond 10 rounds, and every subsequent check will fail.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have revamped my code and gotten rid of most global variables. That completeRounds function I currently have set to: function completeRound() {
        let userScore = parseInt(document.getElementById("userScore").innerText);
        let computerScore = parseInt(document.getElementById("compScore").innerText);
        
        roundsPlayed++
        console.log(roundsPlayed);
        if (roundsPlayed === 9) {
            limitGameToBestOutOfNine();
            resetScore();
        }

}  which may cause game "ties" to actually credit a winner, one or the other.